# ngrx forms 8 reducer does not update state

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm using ngrx-forms (specifically the ngrx 8 syntax) to sync my form and state store. The form state updating actions are successfully dispatched e.g.

```js
{
  controlId: 'adForm.location.community',
  value: 'wst',
  type: 'ngrx/forms/SET_VALUE'
}
```

However, the state always stays the same, the above produces no diff in the Redux dev tools.

My reducer looks as follows:

```js
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialAdFormStoreState,
  onNgrxForms(),
  // Other action handlers
  // ...
)

export const adFormReducer = wrapReducerWithFormStateUpdate(
  reducer,
  (s) => s.data.form,
  adFormValidators,
)
```

The initial state is created as follows:

```js
const initialAdFormStoreState: AdFormStoreState = {
  data: {
    form: createFormGroupState<AdForm>('adForm', { /* ... */ })
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

I've checked the updating state documentation countless times and everything looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onNgrxForms()` only checks for forms at the top level of the feature state object. It wasn't updating my state because I had the form at `data.form` since we split state into ui/data. I had to hoist it up a level. Alternatively you can write your own implementation of `onNgrxForms()`.

Comment: Have you got a proper solution for that? I'm struggling with it too.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried writing my own implementation but it wasn't good and started hitting edge cases so I just kept all form states at the feature's top level.

Answer (score 1):

As [Moo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3159486/moo) said, unfortunately, `onNgrxForms()` checks only the top level of the state and you need to write your own implementation.

I had a similar problem, my task was to implement some kind of virtual tabs, that can be stored and displayed independently.

I got two implementations: straight implementation that checks only two-level state (the one that I use in my production project) and more generic implementation that works recursively.

The code is based on [ngrx-forms](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms/tree/master) implementation of `onNgrxForms()`, see links below.

https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms/blob/master/src/reducer.ts
https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms/blob/master/src/state.ts

#### State

```
export interface MyObject {
    property: string;
}

export interface MyObjectFormValue {
    property: string;
}

export interface Substate {
    data: MyObject;
    form: FormGroupState<MyObjectFormValue>;
}

export interface State {
    [id: number]: Substate;
    commonData1: any[];
    commonData2: boolean;
}
```

As you can see, the `State` interface contains some `Substates`, that contain `FormGroupState`. `Substate` can be accessed via indexer but you can write your implementation without indexer, using just your field `data`.

If you want, you can add some common data (fields `commonData1`, `commonData2`) shared between `Substates`.

#### Straight approach

```
import { ALL_NGRX_FORMS_ACTION_TYPES, formStateReducer } from 'ngrx-forms';

function isSubstate(object: any): object is Substate {
    return (
        Boolean(object) &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, 'data') &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, 'form')
    );
}

export function onNgrxFormsDeep(): { reducer: ActionReducer<State>; types: string[] } {
    return {
        reducer: (state, action) =>
            Object.entries(state)
                .filter(([_, value]) => isSubstate(value))
                .reduce(
                    (accum, [key, subState]) => ({
                        ...accum,
                        [key]: {
                            ...subState,
                            form: formStateReducer(subState.form, action)
                        }
                    }),
                    state
                ),
        types: ALL_NGRX_FORMS_ACTION_TYPES
    };
}
```

I use `Object.entries` because I don't know what `Substates` are stored inside `State`, but if the keys of State are predefined, you can just simply access them.

#### Generic approach

```
import { ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { produce } from 'immer';
import { ALL_NGRX_FORMS_ACTION_TYPES, FormState, formStateReducer } from 'ngrx-forms';

interface Match {
    parentObjectPath: string[];
    formStateKey: string;
}

export function onNgrxFormsDeep(): {
    reducer: ActionReducer<any>;
    types: string[];
} {
    return {
        reducer: (state, action) => {
            if (isFormState(state)) {
                return formStateReducer(state, action);
            }

            const matches = searchForms(state);

            if (matches.length) {
                return produce(state, (draftState) => {
                    matches.forEach((match) => {
                        const parent = match.parentObjectPath.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], draftState);
                        const form = match.parentObjectPath.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], state)[match.formStateKey];
                        parent[match.formStateKey] = formStateReducer(form, action);
                    });
                });
            }

            return state;
        },
        types: ALL_NGRX_FORMS_ACTION_TYPES
    };
}

function searchForms(state: any): Match[] {
    const matches: Match[] = [];
    const visits = new Set<any>();
    const parentObjectPath = [];
    searchFormsImpl(null, state);

    return matches;

    function searchFormsImpl(key: string, object: any): void {
        if (visits.has(object)) {
            return;
        }
        visits.add(object);

        if (isFormState(object)) {
            matches.push({ parentObjectPath: [...parentObjectPath], formStateKey: key });
        } else if (isObject(object) || Array.isArray(object)) {
            if (key) {
                parentObjectPath.push(key);
            }
            Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
                searchFormsImpl(k, v);
            });
            if (key) {
                parentObjectPath.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}

function isFormState<TValue = any>(state: any): state is FormState<TValue> {
    return (
        Boolean(state) &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(state, 'id') &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(state, 'value') &&
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(state, 'errors')
    );
}

function isObject(objValue: any): boolean {
    return (
        Boolean(objValue) &&
        typeof objValue === 'object' &&
        (objValue.constructor === Object || objValue.constructor.toString().startsWith('class'))
    );
}
```

This version uses the library `immer` to update state immutably.

Unfortunately, the function `isFormState` is not in public API of the library, so I copied it.

I added a set `visits` to avoid cirricular references problem, because some fields can contain their parents, without it the code will fail with stack overflow error.

Besides that, I wrote the function `isObject` because some properties (of type `number`,  `string`, `function`, etc) should not be checked.